# keep the name of the columns after a each function for ggplot title

Tags: r, ggplot2

i need to use ggplot on a data frame and accordingly assign the name of each plotted column. I built a couple of functions for this scope but the loop inside my main function removes the name of the columns. Here the code so far

Random generated dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales) 

level=c("Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Neither agree or disagree","Disagree", "Strongly disagree",NA)
df <- data.frame(pre_1=as.character(sample(c("Yes","No", NA), 20, replace = T)), 
                                    pre_2=as.character(sample(level, 20, replace = T)),
                                    post_1=as.character(sample(level, 20, replace = T)),
                                    post_2=as.character(sample(level, 20, replace = T)),
                                    stringsAsFactors=T)
```

Dummy function to avoid ordering the factor for yes-no items

```
dummy <- function(v, naVal = NULL) { 
  v1 <- na.omit(v)
  # remove NA's
  v2 <- as.integer(as.factor(v1))
  if( !is.numeric(v2) ) stop("Only numeric vectors are accepted.")
  # get unique values
  v_unique <- unique(v2)
  # remove 'naVal's
  v_unique2 <- v_unique[! v_unique %in% naVal]
  # count number of unique values and check whether all values are integers
  if ( length(unique(v_unique2)) > 2L || 
       any(as.integer(v_unique2) != v_unique2) ) FALSE else TRUE
}
```

Plotting function

```
dfplot_pre <- function(df){
  select(df, starts_with("pre_")) %>%
    for (col in .){
      name =names(col)
      if (dummy(as.character(col)) == TRUE) {
        data.frame(col)  %>%
          na.omit() %>%
          ggplot(.,aes(x=.))  +  
          geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), stat="count") + 
          geom_text(aes( label =paste(round((..count..)/sum(..count..)*100),"%"), y= (..count..)/sum(..count..)), stat= "count", vjust = -.5)+
          scale_y_continuous(labels=percent,limits = c(-0, 1)) + 
          scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) + 
          ylab("Relative Frequencies (%)") + 
          theme_bw() +
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) -> dummyplot
        print(dummyplot)
        print(name)}
      else {
        factor(col, c("Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Neither agree or disagree","Disagree", "Strongly disagree"),ordered = T ) %>% 
        data.frame() %>%
          na.omit() %>%
          ggplot(.,aes(x=.))  +  
          geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), stat="count") + 
          geom_text(aes( label =paste(round((..count..)/sum(..count..)*100),"%"), y= (..count..)/sum(..count..)), stat= "count", vjust = -.5)+
          scale_y_continuous(labels=percent,limits = c(-0, 1)) + 
          scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) + 
          ylab("Relative Frequencies (%)")+
          theme_bw() +
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)
          ) -> contplot
        print(contplot)
      }}  
}
```

The print at the end of the if statements should return the name of the column but it returns NULL. This is because of the `for (col in .){}` remove the name of the columns of the data frame.

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

need to change the each function with seq

```
  dfplot_post <- function(df){
  select(data, starts_with("pre_")) %>% 
    length() %>% 
    seq(1,.,1)  %>% 
    for (i in .){
      if (dummy(as.character(select(data, starts_with("pre_"))[[i]])) == TRUE) {
        data.frame(select(data, starts_with("pre_"))[[i]])  %>%
          na.omit() %>%
          ggplot(.,aes(x=.))  +  
          geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), stat="count") + 
          geom_text(aes( label =paste(round((..count..)/sum(..count..)*100),"%"), y= (..count..)/sum(..count..)), stat= "count", vjust = -.5)+
          scale_y_continuous(labels=percent,limits = c(-0, 1)) + 
          scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) + 
          ylab("Relative Frequencies (%)") + 
          ggtitle(names(select(data, starts_with("post_")))[i]) +
          theme_light(base_size = 18) +
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
          theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) -> dummyplot
        print(dummyplot)}
      else {
        factor(select(data, starts_with("pre_"))[[i]], c("Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Neither agree or disagree","Disagree", "Strongly disagree"),ordered = T ) %>% 
          data.frame() %>%
          na.omit() %>%
          ggplot(.,aes(x=.))  +  
          geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), stat="count") + 
          geom_text(aes( label =paste(round((..count..)/sum(..count..)*100),"%"), y= (..count..)/sum(..count..)), stat= "count", vjust = -.5)+
          scale_y_continuous(labels=percent,limits = c(-0, 1)) + 
          scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) + 
          ylab("Relative Frequencies (%)")+
          ggtitle(names(select(data, starts_with("pre_")))[i]) +
          theme_light(base_size = 18) +
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + 
          theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))-> contplot
        print(contplot)
      }}  
}
```